# How do I programmatically add an assembly reference to a project?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have been trying to use Roslyn to parse a solution file and programmatically add a custom assembly reference to each project in the solution.

I tried using the following code snippet to do the same:

```
//The name of the DLL is customLib.dll
var reference = MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("customLib");
project = project.AddMetadataReference(reference);
```

However, it encounters a FileNotFoundException while creating the MetadataReference.

So, my question is : **How do I specify the path at which Roslyn needs to check for the specified dll**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference` is used to get references to assemblies in the GAC. Try this:

```
project = project.AddMetadataReference(new MetadataFileReference("<path>"));
```