# Is it possible to add folder reference path while loading the project via roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

In the below code snippet:

```
IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject(projectFilePath);
```

I want to give a folder reference path to load all the MetadataReferences of the project of which csproj file path I am giving to the method.

As I understand it is possible to add assembly reference programatically:

[How do I programmatically add an assembly reference to a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287123/how-do-i-programmatically-add-an-assembly-reference-to-a-project)

But this option is useless for me, I need folder reference like in visual studio.

The effect of unloaded references is that semantic analysis is wrong (There are errortypes for members contained in references). I could not find any solution.

Any workaround solutions are also welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify an additional reference path with the current CTP. The only workaround you would have is to either update your project files to update the references before loading with Roslyn, or modifying your project file to contain the  property vs. it living in the .user file.

Comment: Is it sth that is planned to be added in upcoming releases?

Comment: I think we have added support for passing arbitrary MSBuild properties which would cover your scenario. I'll follow up with an internal work item. As usual, I can't promise if or when we'll add things, as features are always subject to change.